# Relationship of two variables over multiple time points

Tags: time-series, correlation, variable

I am very inexperienced with statistics, so any help is appreciated! I would also greatly appreciate any recommended reading as well.

We have a cohort of 10 subjects, whom we have looked at two different values (x and y). We have measured these values multiple times during multiple time points.

For example,

Subject #1 had three measurements of x and y on days 1, 15, and 29

Subject #2 had four measurements of x and y on days 1, 45, 56, and 80

Given the nature of x and y, I will not be able to predict where x or y will be based on the time alone. The values are sometimes higher or lower over the course of the data collection.

What I am trying to figure out is:

1) Among all subjects, is there a relationship between x and y? (i.e. if x changes, will y change as well?)

2) If #1 is true, is there a "time lag" between when x changes and when y changes? (i.e. if x changes, it will take 7 days on average for y to change).

The current hypothesis is that y will not change if x changes.

What would be the most appropriate method to figure out both questions?

Thank you in advance!